# "This build is missing export compliance information."

Tags: ios, encryption, build, standards-compliance

I deployed a build to *iTunesConnect*, prior to testing with *TestFlight*.

However next to the app icon there is a message: `"This build is missing export compliance information."`

Expanding the message:

```
If you are making use of ATS or making a call to HTTPS please note that you are required to submit a year-end self classification report to the US government
```

In my app there are two button:

1. First one redirects to the AppStore page of my app using `UIApplication.shared.openURL(<reviewURL>)`
2. Second one uses `UIActivityViewController` to share a link to my app AppStore page.

My app also uses AdMob, so GoogleAds framework is embedded. It makes HTTPS requests.

So, what should I answer for: "Does my app uses encryption" - Yes or No?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add this to the plist to remove that alert from itunes

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>  
<false/>
```

answer is NO

Comment: OK. Thank you! ;-)

Comment: My App uses HTTPS, is it required to add 

<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>  
<true/>
?